# Can we define size for font-size:x-large as a length value

Tags: css

I have looked in the moz documentation on font-size 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)
 and curious if we could define the unit for absolute size values like below,

```
font-size: small; /* => 10px */
font-size: medium; /* => 15px */
font-size: large; /* => 20px */
font-size: x-large;/* => 25px */
```

like so, instead of taking browser default.

Comment: You mean remap the constant value "x-large" from something the browser intends to a value you want (e.g. 25px)?

Comment: @FabianSchöner Yes, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)
those are absolute-size keywords:

> Absolute-size keywords, based on the user's default font size (which is medium).

As per their definition *"based on the **user's** default font size"* you pretty much cant overload those values because they are multiples (of fractions) of the **user's** default font size which means you would have to change the **user's** default font size.

You can always set specific values in pixel tho:

```
font-size: 16px;
```

When working with a preprocessor (e.g. https://sass-lang.com/) you could define variables and use them like this:

```
$font-size-xxlarge:25px;

.foo {
  font-size:$font-size-xxlarge;
}
```

This will make font-sizes consistent in your code, wont change the actual absolute-size values for the browser tho.

Comment: +1 for an answer. Although, As with the blogger's WYSIWYG editor it sort of works on these absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change absolutes like `large` but you can use `larger`.

It's rel to the parent.

```
larger, smaller
Relative-size keywords. The font will be larger or smaller relative to the parent element's font size, roughly by the ratio used to separate the absolute-size keywords above.
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the answer. looks like will need to use jQuery map and change all the element property with absolute value to length value.